# Multiple taxes not applied on a checkout

Tags: magento-2.1, tax

I have a magento instance v 2.1.0.

I have created a tax rule as shown in the image below

[image]

I have created two tax rates **CGST@9** and **SGST@9** both at 9% rate and included in the tax rule **GST@18** as shown above.

When I include a product with tax class as **Taxable Goods** and place order, at checkout only one tax is being applied on the product as shown in below image

[image]

Only SGST@9 tax rate is being applied i.e. only 9% tax is applied instead of 18%.

Why both of the tax rates are not applied?

Answer (score 0):

Might be helpful for other,

You need to change the priority in Tax Rules different for different taxes,

and mark sub total as tick for one

[image]

It worked for me ..